# Windows 7 change specific colors

Tags: windows-7, colors

The other day I accidentally dropped my HP laptop and laptop LED screen is broken. Not physically broken, but screen goes Red. Black color turns Red.

I know this is hardware level problem. And even BIOS looks completely Red.

When LED try to display `#000000` color, it turns it into Red color.

But I observed one thing, specifically in Windows 7, color `#272727` which is very nearer to black works completely fine (It doesn't turn to Red).

Is there any way to define pure black color of whole system as any other color? Is it possible by changing registry values or any other way ?

P.S. I am buying new screen though. I am just curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no facility that does this in Windows 7 to my knowledge.

A video driver would be able to do this by changing all `#000000` pixels to another color.  But I do not know of any driver that has a feature to do that.

It is possible in theory, but not practical in practice.